# Is there a reason to create a new HttpCookie just to expire it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am just about to write some code to clear a cookie in my ASP.NET site using C#. Although I've mostly come across this way of clearing cookie,

```
if (Request.Cookies["my_cookie"] != null)
{
   HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("my_cookie");
   myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20);
   Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

I'm curious about the difference between using the above method and this:

```
if (Request.Cookies["my_cookie"] != null)
{
   Response.Cookies["my_cookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-20);
}
```

My confusion is Why create a new instance of `HttpCookie`, set the `Expires`, then Add it to the Response, when you can just set the `Expires` directly in `Response.Cookies`? Is there any difference in complexity between those two? I've tested both and I know they work. I just want to know which one is preferred and for what reason.

Comment: @user2864740 cookies are not auto-magically copied from request to response (unlike other way around - adding cookie to response adds it to request).